# Begin with emotion, finish with dread

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

> You begin as an emotion the movies stress
>   Change your beginning to the fourth to never be separated again
>   Remove your point to transform into a deer
>   Turn your shreik into a cross to be referenced as a point
>   Fill your hole with eh to be an digital audiotape
>   Bring back your shreik to be known as romantic
>   Move your shreik to your eh and add an H to your name to be what everyone dreads

What have you turned into, and how?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have turned into:

> **death**

**Explanation:**

You begin as an emotion the movies stress:

> **love** - Love is an emotion, and many movies have a romantic plot.

Change your beginning to the fourth to never be separated again:

> **dove** - Change "l" to "d". "d" is the 4th letter of the alphabet. Doves symbolize peace and unity (lack of separation).

Remove your point to transform into a deer:

> **doe** - Remove the "v". "v" has a pointed bottom. A doe is a female deer.

Turn your shriek into a cross to be referenced as a point:

> **dot** - Change "e" to "t". "e" sounds like a shriek, as in "eeee". "t" looks like a cross. A dot can also be called a point.

Fill your hole with eh to be an digital audiotape:

> **dat** - Change the "o" to "a". "o" looks like a hole. "eh" sounds like "a". DAT stands for Digital Audio Tape.

Bring back your shriek to be known as romantic:

> **date** - Bring back the "e" on the end. Dates are romantic...hopefully.

Move your shriek to your eh and add an H to your name to be what everyone dreads:

> **death** - Move the "e" to the "a" and add "h" to the end. Everyone dreads death.

Comment: Well that's depressing :/

Comment: Brilliant answer. Well done.